# Windows / Multiple python versions / How to get Pip or Venv command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get multiple versions of Python in my Computer (current version is 3.7)

I have downloaded a 3.6 embed version : python-3.6.8rc1-embed-amd64

When I run python from this new directory, it works and I can run sys module inside Python Prompt.

But in the case of Venv or Pip (outside Python Prompt)

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'venv'

What would be the correct way ?

thanks

Comment: Pretty much I would recommend you go through this tutorial (its in depth but understandable): https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ A shorter primer for just `virtualenv` is here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-virtual-environments-in-python/ If you are already doing this correctly, it may be that you are just not activating the environment you want to use.

Comment: What command do you run to get this error? Please include this information in the question. There are thousands of questions about ModuleNotFoundError here, so we need more information to determine what's the problem. NB: `venv` is a standard Python library that exists since Python 3.3. I'm not sure what the "3.6 embed version" is. Could you add a link to it in your question?

Comment: Off-topic: Python 3.6 is already [end-of-life](https://peps.python.org/pep-0494/#lifespan). You might consider starting with a newer version that is still supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually no need to use embed version. Installing differents python versions is ok

E.G I have three differents versions in this folder C:\Users\FB088ABL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python

When I need to source a specific version for a project, I am using :

*[absolute path to the version I want]*`python -m venv .env`

Then when you type `python` in this environment, it supersedes your path environment

NB: with the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) there is no need to specify the full path.